# Kubuntu 18.04 - Laptop won't recognize external monitor

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

TL;DR: Was using Ubuntu 18.04. Laptop suddenly stopped recognizing external ASUS monitor. Formated laptop and installed Kubuntu 18.04. Problem persists.

Hi everyone. Last week I was using Ubuntu and suddenly my laptop stopped detecting my ASUS external monitor. I didn't try to solve the issues because I was on exams at college and I can still work with my laptop's monitor. However, after understanding how better KDE is than Gnome3, I decided to install Kubuntu 18.04 because I'm too lazy to install KDE on Ubuntu and I also had some other issues that I guessed would be solved with a fresh OS install. And they did, except that the laptop still doesn't recognize my external monitor.

The ASUS monitor works, I tested it with a Raspberry Pi. My laptop is an HP Omen, first gen. I think. I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 as my GPU

I've tried this, as other threads suggested:

- Changed my Display Manager to LightDM
- Changed the NVIDIA drivers to Noveau by selecting
  [the second option of this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RdMZ.png)
- Then went back to the first option because that didn't work
- Detect the monitor through NVIDIA X Server Settings at  Server Configuration > Detect displays. Nothing happens.

The output of xrandr with the second monitor connected to the laptop via HDMI:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.01  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91                                                                                                 
   1152x864      60.00                                                                                                                            
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74                                                                                                 
   1024x768      60.04    60.00                                                                                                                   
   960x720       60.00                                                                                                                            
   928x696       60.05                                                                                                                            
   896x672       60.01                                                                                                                            
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82                                                                                                 
   960x600       59.93    60.00                                                                                                                   
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82                                                                                                 
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25                                                                                                          
   840x525       60.01    59.88                                                                                                                   
   864x486       59.92    59.57                                                                                                                   
   800x512       60.17                                                                                                                            
   700x525       59.98                                                                                                                            
   800x450       59.95    59.82                                                                                                                   
   640x512       60.02                                                                                                                            
   720x450       59.89                                                                                                                            
   700x450       59.96    59.88                                                                                                                   
   640x480       60.00    59.94                                                                                                                   
   720x405       59.51    58.99                                                                                                                   
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.01
```

The contents of /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.77  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-14)  Tue Jul 10 23:19:22 PDT 2018

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```